# Export to multiple PNGs from a single PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, export

I don't anything about graphic design so please bear with me.

I bought an icon set and it included the psd for the icons. I change the color of the icons and now need to export all the icons to PNGs. That is, a PNG for each icon. All the icons are in the same PSD.

How can I do this? Do I have to select one icon at a time and export them individually or is there a way to export the whole batch at once to individual PNGs?

Comment: I have it in AI format as well, in case someone has a solution using AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to export them individually.

Look at the PSD...the icons are all in one layer but arranged on a grid..ie. each icon is 32x32, 64x64 etc. If this is the case you can either change your document grid spacing (edit > preferences > grids & guide) to match, or create "guides" (view > new guide) to match.

Then with grids/guides setup...and view > "snap to" turned on you can use the 'rectangular marquee' tool to select each icon, copy then File > New (should already the same size as the icon in the clipboard) then paste and save for web.

Comment: If the Icons are arranged in a grid-fashion, you're better off using the `Slice` tool and [`Divide Slice`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-754f.html).

Comment: @Farray That's the solution: Slice it and when using "Save to web" select only images (no html). Then you'll get individual files.

Answer (score 0):

If the icons are in layers you could use File > Extract Assets or select the layers you want and right click on the layer and choose 'Extract Assets…' from the context menu in the new version of Photoshop and do the export you need.